# Does LEGO own patent US 8,292,744 B2?

Tags: ownership, assignee, assignment-history, us8292744

In reference to the patent: [US 8,292,744 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US8292744)

It looks like LEGO so I need to know if they own it or not.

Answer (score 1):

On Google Patents, note that the Original Assignee is "Roblox Corporation". From an [WSJ blog](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2013/08/20/roblox-sees-strong-future-for-world-building-games/) in 2013:

> Roblox raised about $7.2 million from investors including Altos
>   Ventures and First Round Capital

So, no, there does not appear to be any association with LEGO. This is a US company based in San Mateo, California.

For completeness, if you check the [Assignment history](http://assignment.uspto.gov/#/search?q=8292744) for the patent, you will see that it has not been reassigned.